# Restarting a timer under certain conditions

Tags: sockets, select, udp, timeout

I'm using `select()` and I only want to restart the timer under a certain condition.

So far I have this:

```
    int t = 1; 
    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int sret;


 while(1){

      FD_ZERO(&readfds);
      FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);


     if(prevAck != ack || t == 1){ // only restart timer when necessary 
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 10000; // 10 msec
        t = 0;
      }

      sret = select(sockfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

      if(sret == 0){ //timeout
        printf("%s\n", "Time Out!!!!!");
        t = 1;
       }
       else
          printf("%s\n", "No time Out!!!!!");


}
```

will this work as expected? ie: only restart the timer when the condition is met or when there was a timeout

Comment: Is there something keeping you from running/compiling this to check whether this will "work as expected"? There's a nice online site called ideone.com that will let you compile and test code of all kinds of languages in your browser really quickly.

Comment: What exactly is your intention regarding `select()`'s behaviour for the case the condition is false?

Comment: if the condition is false, I want to still check if the file descriptor has data for reading, but do not want to reset the timer ie: contonue using previous timer value

Comment: "*continue using previous timer value*" certain implementations of `select()` modify the values of `timeout`. If this is the case you *need* to reintialise them before reusing them. See your implementation's documentation on `select()` for details.